# EF Core in class library and use from API project - How to pass config information to class library?

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

Ive setup a solution with a .net core class library project and an asp.net core web api project.  To use my class library I added the interface via ConfigureServices, where DataRepo is a class in the class library.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IDataRepo, DataRepo>();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

This class library needs to get the environment-specific connection string that will be in the API project file appsettings.json.  How can I pass config settings over to it?  Also, I wan to add an EF core datamodel in the library project and Id rather not register a DbContext with the API project, but rather in the constructor of my library, use the connection info to pass along with the config in the DbContext.  First things first, How can I get the config settings from the appsettings.json to my class library?

```
namespace DataLib
{
    public class DataRepo : IDataRepo
    {

        public DataRepo()
        {

        }

        public string GetHello()
        {
            return "hello from lib";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you only wants to share configuration between a lib project and a website project , you'd better use dependency injection to do that .

A lib project should not care about the location of the configuration file . Anytime we need a configuration in our lib project , let's say a `ConnectionString` , we should just ask for it .

The first to do is to add a package reference in the lib project :

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.1.1" />
```

And then inject an `IConfiguration` when we need it . For example , we should have a `IConfiguration` object injected in `DataLib`:

```
namespace DataLib
{
    public class DataLib: IDataRepo
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration ;
        public DataLib(IConfiguration config ){
            this._configuration=config;
        }

        public string ConnectionString{
            get{
                return _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `IConfiguration` doesn't care where is the configuration file or which kinds of arguments are passed by command-line when started . Actually , it doesn't care about anything . The DataLib just uses a simple POCO .

When we need the class lib in main project , we can simply add the service to DI container by :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddScoped<DataLib.DataLib>(); // if you want to use DbContext , just use AddScoped<TService>()

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

That's all we have to do . The `appsettings.json` and other configurations will be built into an instance of `IConfiguration` and then be injected to the lib project automatically.

2. There're also other solutions , such as using linked files and so on . However , the approach above keeps the DataLib a plain POCO . This is great . As a lib is always used by a main project , we don't need to care about the configuration or how it is created . The main project will take care of it .

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: While the crux of the answer is correct, i.e. injecting the config, the approach is wrong. If your class needs a connection string, *pass it the connection string*, not `IConfiguration`. For one, you should not use `IConfiguration` directly anyways, but rather inject strongly-typed configuration classes. Second, the class library now has a dependency both on the particular methodology for obtaining configuration *and* a magic string (`DefaultConnection`), which assumes far too much knowledge about the app that will be utilizing it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt , Thanks for your advice . But I still can't understand why we  should not inject a `IConfiguration` . In my opinion , the `IConfiguration` interface has a strongly-typed method of `GetConnectionString(string)`  . As a result , the lib project itself doesn't need to care about the magic connection string .  As for the lib knowing too much knowledge about the main proj , what if the lib wants to use other configurations other than connection string ? In that case , will it be suitable to have a `IOption<T> ` injected ?

Comment: The "magic string" is the name of the connection string in your code ("DefaultConnection"). Magic strings are bad and universally a sign of bad design. With that, the app *must* name the connection string that in its config or the library will fail, and fail with an error that does not instruct how to fix it. There's no way to use `IConfiguration` for this purpose directly without the use of that magic string, which means its out right from the gate.

Comment: As for other config, there may be scenarios where `IOptions<T>` may be appropriate, but generally, you'd simply use a config class from the library. Then, in your app, you can either use this library class directly for your strongly-typed config, or more likely, map from your config to this library class. Again, the idea is that the library should have no knowledge of anything outside of it's specific purpose. If it needs config, it should have it's own setup for that, and your app should merely translate your config into what the library understands. Otherwise, you're bleeding business logic.

Comment: @ChrisPratt  Thanks . I agree with the most of what you say completely  . Particularly , the magic string of `DefaultConnection` I used here is a bad idea .  I used to think that OP wanted to share all kinds of configurations between the lib project and app project , so I just took the `ConnectionStrings` as an example  . (OP says that he want to "pass config settings over" ).  If there's only one connection string needed to be injected , and I'm sure there will be only one string needed to be injected in the future  ,  it's better to use your approach .  Thanks for you detailed explaination .

Answer (score 5):

If your class needs a connection string, then simply give it the connection string. You can utilize the overload for `AddScoped` that takes an `Action<T>`.

First, add a constructor that takes your connection string:

```
public class DataRepo : IDataRepo
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DataRepo(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
    }
}
```

Then, in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<IDataRepo>(p => new DataRepo(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Foo")));
```

Your class should not know or care where the connection string actually comes from, which is why other approaches, such as injecting `IConfiguration` are wrong here.